# Podio .Net API Importer value checking

Tags: .net, api, podio

We are using the import API functionality to create items in podio (personal information items) which is all working fine, however, we have to then attach other podio sub-items to the first ones that were created(counseling sessions). These items have a 1 to many relationship. Is there a way to check for the value prior to creating each item? For instance I want to attach the sub items to the master item by matching client IDs during the import. I want to limit API calls as much as possible so running a search or filter would most likely not be great for me unless that is the only option.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: PS I've already read the API documentation which isn't as useful as I would have hoped.

Comment: You want to check if the sub item is already attached to the master item before you update the master item, right?

Comment: No, I want to check each item that’s coming in from the import, for a value (client ID) which exists on the csv file in order to assign that item to the correct master item that already exists in podio which contains the same client ID